# Curve fit passing through initial point and slope

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of data points, and I want to fit a curve such that the curve passes through the initial point and has the same initial slope. I found a few questions on the forum where point constraint was enforced, and have my code working up to that by using the `sigma` variable in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

x_data = np.linspace(1,2)
p = [2, 3, -4, 1];
y_data = np.polyval(p, x_data)

sigma = np.ones(len(x_data))
sigma[[0]] = 0.01
m_0 = 8
def fit_func(x, a, b, c):    
    return a*np.exp(x)+np.sin(x)+c

popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, x_data, y_data, sigma=sigma)
plt.plot(x_data,y_data)
plt.plot(x_data, fit_func(x_data, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]))
plt.grid()
```

Is there a way to enforce the initial slope of `m_0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you always write the non dimensional argument of a function in terms of a dimensional quantity multiplied by a |frequency|, even if the frequency is identically equal to 1.

```
λ = 1
y = a sin(λx) + b exp(λx) + c
```

The parameters `a`, `b`, and `c` now have the same dimension, the dimension of `y`.

Now, consider that you want `y(0) = a×0 + b×1 + c = y0` hence `b = y0-c`, and you want `dydx(0) = a λ cos(0) + b λ exp(0) = (a+b) λ = slope` hence `(a+y0-c) λ = slope` and eventually `a = (slope/λ) + c - y0`.

At this point, I hope that you recognize that the function you want to fit has effectively a single free parameter, and that you must define the function to fit as below

```
λ = 1.0
def fit_func(x, c):    
    return (slope/λ+c-y0)*np.sin(λ*x)+(y0-c)*np.sin(λ*x)+c
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, but this was just a simplified example which I made up to define my problem. This method of eliminating the constraints by reducing the number of free variables might get tricky as the fitting function has a larger number of unknown's (say 5). Is there a more general way to do it ?

Comment: @aaquib _"say 5"_ then you solve for two parameters in terms of the remaining three. What is the problem?

Comment: It worked for me. I was just assuming that there would be an approach where I won't need to use pen and paper.

Comment: @aaquib Keep always pen&paper close to your brain ;-) Thank you for the recognition you gave to my answer.